# HTTP to HTTPS redirect in IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, server, iis-8, windows-server-2012

https://testitnow.in/edgar is the website which is built on ASP. I configured auto redirect in IIS but still, if I type testitnow.in in the web browser I'm getting the following error - "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied."

But if I type https://testitnow.in or www.testitnow.in it is redirecting to https://testitnow.in. Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I added this code already. But then also redirecting is not happening. I need HTTP and HTTPS both should work on the browser. But if users type HTTP forcefully it should tell the users this site is not secure. Can I do it on IIS?

Comment: you can detect HTTP or HTTPS using JavaScript

Comment: after you can give warning message to user